# serverless error: "bucket already exist" while deploying to Gitlab

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, aws-serverless

I am newbee to serverless stack,Following is the serverless.yml file. On deploying this in GitLab I get error as:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

   An error occurred: S3XPOLLBucket - bucket already exists.
```

Serverless.yml file is :

```
service: sa-s3-resources


plugins:
  - serverless-s3-sync
  - serverless-s3-remover

custom:
  basePath: sa-s3-resources
  environment: ${env:ENV}

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${env:STAGE}
  region: ${env:AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
  environment:
    STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}



resources:
  Resources:
    S3XPOLLBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: gs-sa-xpoll-file-${self:custom.environment}-${self:provider.stage}
    S3JNLBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: gs-sa-jnl-file-${self:custom.environment}-${self:provider.stage}
```

Answer (score 0):

An Amazon S3 bucket name is globally unique, and the namespace is shared by all AWS accounts. This means that after a bucket is created, the name of that bucket cannot be used by another AWS account in any AWS Region until the bucket is deleted.

**That means you have to choose a unique name that has not already chosen by someone else (or even you in a different development stack) globally**

More details

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html

Comment: I got the solution for this. Had to tear down the pipepline and then teared it up. It worked fine then.

Comment: how did you do that?